# UK Off-Peak Day return ticket with restriction forcing use of specific trains?

Tags: trains, tickets, national-rail

I have an Off-Peak Day Return ticket from Hull [HUL] to Leeds [LDS]. When I purchased this ticket through the Northern app, I also reserved seats for both legs.

When I collected the tickets, I was surprised to see that the restriction code [TD](http://nre.co.uk/TD). The key part of this restriction (as I read it) is "Seat reservations are compulsory." for outward travel, and "Not applicable" for return travel.

Does this mean that I must travel on the reserved train for one or both of the legs (and not on another service)?

Note: I contacted TransPennine Express about this, and they claim this restriction code does not apply to an Off-Peak Day Return, and I am free to use any service. This is one possible answer, preferably with an explanation of to why tickets might have incorrect restriction codes, and some references as to how to tell the restriction can be ignored.

[image: The tickets in question, showing restriction TD]

Comment: What was the price of the ticket? Were any railcards applied?

Comment: The ticket was £21.70, no railcards.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no mandatory seat reservation required on the fare: http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=HUL&dest=LDS&tkt=CDR Possibly an IT glitch on the ticket printer?

Comment: That is possible; nonetheless the ticket is clearly labelled with restriction TD; is the canonical restriction the one printed on the ticket, or the one in the fare system?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of linking this on [Railforums](http://www.railforums.co.uk/showthread.php?t=149559), as it's an interesting question and it's possible someone there has an answer.

Comment: This is what I hate about the new design of ticket - they "simplified it to make it clearer", yet put things like "restrictions apply, see nre.co.uk" instead of the much simpler and clearer "not valid before 10:00" (or whatever) - the old design was much clearer...

Comment: @NickC The old design didn't say "Not valid before 10:00". The old design said "SEE RESTRICTNS". If you were VERY lucky it then printed the two character code above that text, but you had to know to go to http://nres.co.uk/XX (where XX is the two-character code) yourself.

Comment: @Muzer true, but the rest of the old design was much clearer - they made most of it worse, and didn't improve the one bit that needed it!

Comment: @muzer, thanks for posting it to Railforums; in reply to the comment there (I don't have an account, so perhaps you would be kind enough to add it), the tickets were collected in Hull from one of the TPE machines there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others noted in the comments, this is clearly an error either in the data or with the machine (though I can't work out exactly where the TD might have come from). I would print out your correspondence with TPE in the very unlikely event you are challenged; this authorisation should be enough to override any (theoretical, since it's completely inconceivable to me that anyone would question this ticket) issues.